# How percentages widths in table cells work in HTML?

Tags: html

I have been wondering quite a long , that how the percentage width in table cells work in HTML.

**Case 1: No table width specified, single row and columns are not given full space**

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td width="25%">mango</td>
        <td width="25%"">apple</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**Case 2: No table width specified,single row and columns are given full space**

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td width="50%">mango</td>
        <td width="50%"">apple</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**Case 3: No table width specified,single row and columns are given more than 100% space**

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td width="50%">mango</td>
        <td width="50%"">apple</td>
        <td widht="100%">guava</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**Case 4: No table width specified, multiple rows specified and columns are giving following percentage configurations**

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td width="33%">mango</td>
        <td width="33%"">apple</td>
        <td widht="33%">guava</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="50%">papaya</td>
        <td width="50%">pomengrante</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Their outputs I am not able to correlate , please help me in this

Comment: What is the real question? You have this cases but what happens when you try them, and what are your expectations?

Comment: These are giving very weird outputs,  can you just run them individually and see. 

Like in case 1: 

I am not able to analyse that in what respect it will take 25%, is it 25% of the entire space or something else.

Answer (score 0):

The percentage will works depending On any Screen Resolution Equal to 100% So You Divide That Percentage In To Your Requirement Measurements In Percentages Example As Given below,(In Table tr width(100%)=(Addition of td(widths))

```html
      <table style="width:100%;" border="1">
      <tr>
       <td wdith="50%">Mango</td>
       <td wdith="50%">Lemon</td>
      </tr> 
   <!--You Given For 1st Record measurements Then Automatically Adjested 2nd Record Also Depend Upon 1st Record-->
      <tr>
       <td>some Item</td>
       <td>some Item</td>
     </tr>
    </table>
      <!--This Is Another Type Of Table-->
      <h3>This Is Another Type Of Table</h3>
       <table style="width:100%;" border="1">
       <tr>
        <td wdith="33%">Mango</td>
        <td wdith="34%">Lemon</td>
        <td wdith="33%">Something</td>
       </tr> 
   <!--You Given For 1st Record measurements Then Automatically Adjested 2nd Record Also Depend Upon 1st Record-->
       <tr>
       <td>some Item</td>
       <td>some Item</td><td>some Item</td>
       </tr>
      </table>
      <h3>This Is Another Type Of Table</h3>
      <table style="width:100%;" border="1">
      <tr>
      <td wdith="25%">Mango</td>
      <td wdith="25%">Lemon</td>
      <td wdith="25%">Something</td>
      <td wdith="25%">Something</td>
      </tr> 
      <!--You Given For 1st Record measurements Then Automatically Adjested 2nd Record Also Depend Upon 1st Record-->
      <tr>
      <td>some Item</td>
     <td>some Item</td>
     <td>some Item</td>
     <td>some Item</td>
     </tr>
    </table>
```

Answer (score -1):

The cells will work with relation to their table, but also they need to take up 100% of the table width. So that makes your case1 not work. it will split it up as 50%. But a case where you set this will work, as it's 100% of the table width.

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/39vpj306/)

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td width="20%">mango</td>
        <td width="80%">apple</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

If you need something to take up 25-25, then maybe you should look into using divs instead.

Also your last case will not work as you need to have the same amount of cells in the table.

Comment: the explanation is not clear, maybe some work can help someone to have your same understanding